# C# pattern match Task<T> and get it's value

Tags: c#

I am wondering how to pattern match a `Task<T>`. More specifically given variable of static type `object` how to get its `Result` property.

Basically, give:

```
object obj = new Task<string>() // or maybe Task<IEnumerable<...>>

object result = obj... // obj.Result?
```

Comment: Are you trying to pattern match a `Task<object>` (where `T` is unknown until runtime)?

Comment: Yes, it is known at runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you know the generic type of task, you can use reflection to get the value of `Result` property:

```
Type knownInRuntimeType = ...; // e.g., Task<string> or Task<IEnumerable<int>>
Task task = ...; // e.g., Task<string> or Task<IEnumerable<int>>

// result is string or IEnumerable<int>
object result = knownInRuntimeType.GetProperty("Result").GetValue(task);
```

If your `knownInRuntimeType` is actually not a type of task, but a type of result (i.e. `string` or `IEnumerable<int>`), then you need to construct a generic type:

```
Type knownInRuntimeResultType = ...; // string or IEnumerable<int>
Type taskType = typeof(Task<>).MakeGenericType(knownInRuntimeResultType); 
Task task = ...; // e.g., Task<string> or Task<IEnumerable<int>>    

// result is string or IEnumerable<int>
object result = taskType.GetProperty("Result").GetValue(task);
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

The *simplest* approach would be to use dynamic typing:

```
dynamic obj = new Task<string>(); // etc
object result = obj.Result;
```

You could always check whether `obj` is a `Task` of some kind first (using the non-generic `Task` base class). If you really, really want to guard against a user-defined subclass of `Task` other than `Task<T>`, you could do everything via reflection yourself - but it'll be a lot more work.

I'm not generally fond of dynamic typing, and I'd try to avoid getting into this situation in the first place if possible, but that should work fine.